# Spring Boot app having trouble with logback.groovy config file

Tags: spring-boot, logback, fileappender, logback-groovy

I am trying to get Spring Boot working with Logback and am running into an error/issue that I can't figure out.

To reproduce this issue in its entirety, I created a [Spring Boot Example repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/spring-boot-example) on GitHub, but essentially, this is my `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  config: 'logback.groovy'
server:
  port: 9200
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
```

And my `logback.groovy`:

```
statusListener(OnConsoleStatusListener)

def LOG_PATH = '/opt/springbootexample/logs/springbootexample'

appender('CONSOLE', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
    }
}

appender('FILE', FileAppender) {
    file = "${LOG_PATH}.log"
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = '%msg%n'
        outputPatternAsHeader = true
    }
}

appender('ROLLING', RollingFileAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        Pattern = '%d %level %thread %mdc %logger - %m%n'
    }
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
        fileNamePattern = "${LOG_PATH}-%d{yyyy-MM}.zip"
        maxHistory = 30
        totalSizeCap = '1KB'
    }
}

root(INFO, ["CONSOLE", "ROLLING"])
```

I've made sure that `/opt/springbootexample/logs` exists I ran `chmod -R 777 /opt/springbootexample` so my Spring Boot app should have no problem creating log files there and writing to them.

When I run the app locally, I get no errors/exceptions/warnings; everything looks perfectly fine in the console output. I then fire up a browser and point it to `http://localhost:9200`, which should return a simple dummy message, however nothing happens. Even worse, nothing in the console happens either.

The only clue is that after I've shut down the app, if I go to `/opt/springbootexample/logs/springbootexample.log`, its contents are:

```
#logback.classic pattern: %msg%n
```

Which tells me that perhaps there's something misconfigured in my `logback.groovy`'s `FileAppender` maybe? Any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application works (web page loads correctly and shows "Greetings from Spring Boot!"), your logging configuration is just a little wonky.

First problem is that you forgot to add the non-rolling file appender to your root logger. Just add `"FILE"` to the list at the bottom of `logback.groovy` like so:

```
root(INFO, ["FILE", "CONSOLE", "ROLLING"])
//          ^^^^^^^
```

And the log works. Without this, the appender is initialized, the file created with the "weird header" (because you chose to use `outputPatternAsHeader = true`), and nothing is ever appended, because you chose not to.

So the only weird issue is why the web page does not load for you... But perhaps you'll get more info if the log works :)

Try something much simpler for `LOG_PATH`, such as `def LOG_PATH = '/tmp/foo'`, because if that is wrong the server will shut down, and obviously the page will fail to load.

If the path points to something that exists and is writable, it will work.